# Using Class Functions with Pointers after reassigning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I can't really think of a good way to phrase this, but I have no idea why, even though it will compile, it crashes upon execution.
I'm trying to invoke a class function, nextTrain() to my class pointer, apt, and it works before I reassign the pointer, however, after running the line

```
apt = apt->nextTrain()
```

similar class functions cannot be invoked any longer.

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class train {
public:
    string cars[100];
    int index;
    int total;
    train(string n) { cars[0] = n; index=0; total=0;}
    train(string c[100], int ix, int t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            cars[i] = c[i];
        }
        index = ix; total = t;
    }
    train* nextTrain() {
        train t(cars, index, total);
        train* ret = &t;
        ret->atoix(1);
        return ret;
    }
    train* prevTrain() {
        train t(cars, index, total);
        train* ret = &t;
        ret->atoix(-1);
        return ret;
    }
    void atoix(int val) {
        index += val;
    }
    void add(string name) {
        cars[total+1] = name; 
        total++;
    }
    string getName() {
        return cars[index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    train a("Engine");
    train* apt = &a;
    apt->add("Train2");
    apt->add("Train3");
    cout << apt->nextTrain()->getName() << endl;
    apt = apt->nextTrain();
    cout << apt->getName() << endl;
    cout << apt->nextTrain()->getName() << endl;
    cout << apt->prevTrain()->getName() << endl;
    cout << apt->getName() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `train t(cars, index, total); train* ret = &t; return ret;` is: (1) create local variable (2) get pointer of it (3) at end of function, destruct local variable (4) later, access the memory that once held the local variable and get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a closer look at the code in the `nextTrain` function:

```
train t(cars, index, total);
train* ret = &t;
...
return ret;
```

The variable `t` is a *local* variable inside the function. When the function returns `t` will go out of scope and the object will be destructed. However, you return a pointer to this local variable. Once the variable has gone out of scope it doesn't exist anymore, and using this (now invalid) pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

What you should do to solve this problem depends on how you will use it. My suggestion is to not return a pointer from the function, but return an object instance. I.e.

```
train nextTrain() {
    train t(cars, index, total);
    t.atoix(1);
    return t;
}
```

Or even

```
train nextTrain() {
    return train(cars, index+1, total);
}
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake, was able to easily fix by changing the statement to train* ret = new train(cars, index, total);
Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm doing this for a c++ class, so I *have* to return it as a pointer.

Comment: @CollinK Then remember that what you `new` you must `delete`.